# groovy mocks with abstract methods

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, abstract, stub

I have a Java object called Parameter and I'm trying to mock it using groovy. Parameter is an abstract class with 1 abstract method. It also has a non-abstract method called getName(). I'm trying to mock it as follows in Groovy:

```
 def p1 = [name:{"p1Name"}] as Parameter
```

But I get a runtime error because I don't implement the abstract method. If I'm trying to create a mock, why would I need to implement the abstract method?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By mocking using the map you are creating an instance of type Parameter and so it must implement any abstract methods of the Parameter class.

```
abstract class Parameter {
  abstract String getOtherName() 
  String getName() { return "test" }
}

def p1 = [name:{"p1Name"}, getOtherName:{""}] as Parameter
```

Comment: I originally expected this to behave like easymock's class extension, but I since realized it won't. Thank you.